# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (page_backed_instagram_accounts) on node type (Page)

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

According to the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads) when I call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/page_backed_instagram_accounts` using the page token I get an error like this:

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (page_backed_instagram_accounts) on node type (Page)

I've already checked app permission: manage_pages, publish_pages, ads_management and so on..
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a user token, not the page access level token.

I use something like this to get the FacebookId of the page backed Instagram account.

> `/me?fields=instagram_business_account,connected_instagram_account,instagram_accounts{id,username}`

I would suggest to use the [token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) to see the details of the access token.